# Compile Xamarin on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xamarin

My client has a legacy mobile application in which we have to change the api url, but we need to find a way to compile the appliation of Android and/or iOS. There is no necessity to have both OS's working, because we will use this app only to debug a new API so only one of Android/iOS will be enough.

I tried to compile the project in Mono Develop, but I got errors:

> /usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Error MSB3644: No reference sets were found for the item .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111. To resolve this issue, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this version of the platform or change the target platform. .NET Framework Developer Pack packages can be downloaded at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks (MSB3644)

(messages are translated from Polish).

Do you have a way to compile the application on Ubuntu? I have also an access to the Mac computer via MacInCloud service - maybe it will be easier to do it on Mac.

Comment: How about using a Azure DevOps hosted agent? But no, I don't think there is an easy way of compiling the App on Ubuntu. The iOS App needs to be built on a Mac anyways...

Comment: Xamarin bits are only supported on Windows/macOS. So you have to use those two OSs, but not Linux.